# Happy Number from Python list

Tags: python, list

i am an absolute Beginner in Python and im trying to, find happy numbers from a given List. but it doesn't give anything back, i searched for a solution but i couldnt find one. My code is this :

```
a = [1,4,7,82]
def is_happy(a):
    for i in range (len(a)):
        sum = a[i]
        for digit in str(a[i]):
             sum = 0
        while sum != 1 and sum !=4:      
                sum = sum + int(digit) ** 2
        if sum ==1:
                b.append(a[i])
        return b
print(is_happy(a))
```

May you can help me. Thank you!

Comment: What is the definition of your `happy number`?  You should make it clear for us before we can help.

Comment: Look at the indentation of your `return` statement and the indentation of your outer `for` loop.

Comment: Hi, sorry. Sure. Wikipedia says following: In number theory, a happy number is a number which  reaches 1 when replaced by the sum of the square of each digit.  For example 82 is a happy number. (8² + 2² = 68 -> 6² + 8² = 100 -> 1² + 0² + 0² = 1). If a number is no happy number it convergates against 4.

Comment: Can this answer your question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62981881/    
 And please don't use `built-in` `sum` as the variable name.

Comment: I see two other problems: First, you never initialize `b`. Second, there's no point in setting `sum = a[i]`. You not only set `sum` to zero right after that, but you also set it to zero for every iteration of your inner `for` loop, which is redundant. I suspect that both the `while` loop and `if` statement are meant to be within your inner `for` loop, which would make the setting of `sum` to zero multiple times make sense, but that would still make setting `sum` to `a[i]` unnecessary.

Comment: Thank you guys. I made a empty list with b = []. And delete sum = a[i], and it works for the first element of the list. But it doesnt really do the loop..

Comment: Did you fix the indentation of your `return` statement?

Answer (score 0):

Eminos,
I will help with some suggestions.
In Python, white space is very important, and it takes some time for any newbie to get used to.

In `for i in range (len(a)):`, there is an extra space between "range" and "(". It could still run, but is not the preferred style, since it is defined as a range() function.

Code blocks need consistent spacing (left indent).  Each level should be 2 or 4 spaces, with 4 spaces recommended by PEP8 (not tabs).  The below examples have too many spaces in left indent.
`sum = 0`
`sum = sum + int(digit) ** 2`
`b.append(a[i])`

To calculate the squre of a number, it is not necessary to change data type from integer to string.
`squared =  a[i]**2`

To keep track of your squared numbers list, try:

```
    tally = 0
    for i in range(len(a)):
       squared = a[i]**2  # squares each number in list
       tally += squared  # keeps a running sum of squared numbers
```

Generally, I think a function like is_happy should return a true/false statement(s). So a sample returned list can be ["True", "False", "True", "True"] for your input example [1, 4, 7, 82].

More work to do, but hope that will get you started. :-)

Comment: `range (len(a))` is totally fine with the space

Comment: @Mad Physicist, humm that does run on a Python interpreter, but it's still a bad form.  Function calls usually have ( ) coming directly after with no space.

Comment: I just ran it in python 3.6, 3.8, ipython 7.32.0. There is no issue with the space there.

Comment: I agree it runs, but is not preferred style.  From PEP8:  
"Parenthesis No Space: 
The left and right parenthesis and square brackets do not have spaces separating them from their contents. The left parenthesis for a function call is right next to the function name"

run_along(1, 2 * 3, 'hi')
bark()
lst = [1, 2, z * 6]  

https://cs.stanford.edu/people/nick/py/python-style1.html

Answer (score 0):

Converting the integers to strings in order to calculate the sum of squares is not a great idea - better to combine division and modulus. Write a discrete function to do that.

Then write a function that handles one value at a time. Call that multiple times - once for each item in your list.

Here's an approach you could use:

```
def ss(n):
    r = 0
    while n > 0:
        d = n % 10
        r += d * d
        n //= 10
    return r

def is_happy(n):
    if n > 0:
        while True:
            if (n := ss(n)) == 1:
                return True
            if n == 4:
                break
    return False

a = [1, 4, 7, 82]

for n in a:
    print(n, is_happy(n))
```

**Output:**

```
1 True
4 False
7 True
82 True
```

Answer (score 0):

the indents of Python made me suffer..
my solution now looks like:

```
a = [8,2,7,82]
b = []
def is_happy(a):
    for i in range (len(a)):
        sum = a[i]
        while sum!=1 and sum !=4:
            tempsum = 0
            for digit in str(sum):
                tempsum += int(digit) ** 2   
            sum = tempsum
        if sum == 1:
            b.append(a[i])
    return b
print(is_happy(a))
```

and works fine. Thanks for your help and suggestions

Comment: Eminos, nice work.  You got your very first working Python code!   One edit I will still recommend is changing the variable named "sum", because "sum( )" is a built-in function name in Python.  Someone else also commented before on this.  Some possible names are slight variations on the built-in name, ex. a_sum, mysum, summed, sum_a, sum1, etc.  PEP8 style-only points are optional, but they help prevent errors later on.